# Order_by multiple fields, including a boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to order my default_scope in a way that the itens with the boolean `important = true` show first, and all order by `created_at` desc.

So, I have the following code:

```
default_scope order_by(:important => :desc, :created_at => :desc)
```

But, looks like `important` field order is ignored.

How can I made it work?

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:

I just shift the order of the order params and it works:

```
default_scope order_by(:created_at => :desc, :important => :desc)
```

Just that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example on how to sort two columns in rails (probably you might have to slightly modify it to match your requirement), But I think you get the idea

```
<Model>.all(:order => 'important, created_at')
```

HTH